# How can I improve my path tracer?

Tags: graphics, raytracing

[Code_Screenshot_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6l3lf.png)

[Code_Screenshot_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFRAL.png)

[Code_Screenshot_3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJ0jv.png)

[OutPut or Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZbRe.jpg)

Some errors is in result, Corrugated wall appears, under normal circumstances should not have ripples, it should be a simple diffuse material, but now it has ripples,but i cant find the problem.Please help me, thanks.

path trace code :

```
    if (r.depth >= max_ray_depth)
    return L_out;

float pdf;
Vector3D w_in;
Spectrum f = isect.bsdf->sample_f(w_out, &w_in, &pdf);
double cos_theta = std::max(0.0, w_in[2]);
if (cos_theta > 0.0 && pdf > 0.0 )
{
    Vector3D pdir = (o2w * w_in - hit_p ).unit();
    pdir.normalize();
    Ray pr(hit_p, pdir, int(r.depth + 1));
    L_out += (f*cos_theta*trace_ray(pr)*(1.0/pdf));
}
```

Comment: Can you post the actual snippet of code, not just an image?

Comment: Sorry, i posted code.

Comment: Can you specify more than "it has errors". What doesn't work? Does it crash? Can you provide inputs, received outputs and expected outputs for a few cases?

Comment: Corrugated wall appears, under normal circumstances should not have ripples, it should be a simple diffuse material, but now it has ripples.

Comment: Then edit the question to say that. Also, post all code as Code, not as image.

Comment: The code is a little much,And i posted my githup above.
Can you help me see what's wrong? The key code is in pathtracer.cpp

Comment: This question should be closed because it doesn't provide the code as text in the question. If your code is too large, provide a smaller sample that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I provided the key code.

Answer (score 0):

The image suggests your ray tracer is suffering from "*surface acne*", caused when the outbound ray intersects with the surface it just left, due to rounding errors with floating point representation of numbers.

The solution is usually to use *shadow bias* - add a small delta to the "time" (or parametric) value used to start the outbound ray, so that its starting point is slightly away from the surface.

More details are in the Surface Acne section on [this page](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/introduction-to-shading/ligth-and-shadows).

Answer (score 0):

Note: jon-hanson already answered this

Make sure the origins of the bounce rays are very slightly off the surface. You should account for float error.

How to move a vector off the surface:

```cpp
#define FLOAT_ERROR 0.0001f

// in code ...

vec3 normal = object_hit->normal; // I assume this is normalized
vec3 hit_point = object_hit->hit_point;

hit_point += normal * FLOAT_ERROR; //acount for float error

vec3 new_vector_origin = hit_point;
```